# Set Event Listener breakpoint on webpage's javascript

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I need to capture some events from a website. These events get executed in milliseconds when I click a link and it's destroyed after execution. So I need to add a breakpoint to capture that link.

I know Web Inspector does the job but I want to make it a bookmarklet and so I believe that it needs to be done programmatically. Is there any way to do it?

Here is the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkxU1.png)

Comment: Your bookmarklet can't add a breakpoint for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use debugging in chrome, and add breakpoint or add event listener for global event, like click, and step by step go, at right panel .